# Gnome shell calendar + delayed Internet connection

Tags: gnome, evolution, calendar

I've my Google account synced and the calendar works fine. But not always: concretly, if I reboot my computer and log-in in my system before Network Manager has connected to the Internet, the integrated calendar doesn't show my appointments (I must see them througout Evolution). I know no way to force the integrated calendar retry the synchronization once logged in. Neither logging out and logging in, nor rebooting, makes gnome-shell work.

The only way to make the integrated calendar work is rebooting and, in the gdm/lightdm screen, wait until Network Manager has connected before log-in in my system.

What's the problem?

Comment: shell calendar uses `evolution-data-server` as backend. You can open evolution, right click on calendar and select `refresh`. That will start a force refresh. You can change the refresh interval as well. There is also a way to force refresh through `dbus` which can be initiated as script when it connects to internet. You can also try restarting gnome-shell.

Comment: By calendar, do you mean the one from the action bar at the top of the screen?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that by "integrated calendar" you mean the one from the action bar at the top of the screen.

[image: Integrated Calendar showing Exchange & Gmail calendar data]

You can refresh this by opening the **Online Accounts** application and toggling the **Evolution Data Server** entry for *Access Your Google Calendar* off and on again.

Comment: do you know, ~10 years later whether its possible to automate the update?